# Arduino NodeJS Socket.io send json format data not getting the value of variable

Tags: node.js, socket.io, arduino

I'm working with `Arduino` to create JSON.

The code like below

```
String Temperature = "30";
String macAddressDevice = "ABC";
String Humidity = "56";

char json[] = "{\"mac\":macAddressDevice,\"temperature\":Temperature,\"humidity\":Humidity}";

mqtt.publish("TemperatureHumidity", json);
```

When I try to `console.log` in nodejs, it show me not the value but the variable name text:

```
{"mac":macAddressDevice,"temperature":Temperature,"humidity":Humidity}
```

Is there any way how to get the value with above `json` format ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works exactly as you code it, that is, you are sending a string literal instead of concatenating string literal with String variables like `Temperature` and `Humidity`.

String concatenation is something like this:

```cpp
String json= "{\"mac\":macAddressDevice,\"temperature\":" + Temperature + "\"humidity\":" + Humidity + "}";
mqtt.publish("TemperatureHumidity", json.c_str());
```

See [String Addition Operator](https://docs.arduino.cc/built-in-examples/strings/StringAdditionOperator) on how to concatenate variables together to form a String.

The `json.c_str()` converts a String object to a pointer to a char array. See [c_str()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/c_str/) for more information.